# Optimizing Algorithm of large dataset calculations

Tags: python, csv, optimization, pandas, gis

Once again I find myself stumped with pandas, and how to best perform a 'vector operation'. My code works, however it will take a long time to iterate through everything.

What the code is trying to do is loop through `shapes.cv` and determine which `shape_pt_sequence` is a `stop_id`, and then assigns the `stop_lat` and `stop_lon` to `shape_pt_lat` and `shape_pt_lon`, while also marking the `shape_pt_sequence` as `is_stop`.

GISTS

`stop_times.csv` [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/127a960db410f38fc747)

`trips.csv` [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/25d45380e018b7d5c387)

`shapes.csv` [LINK](https://gist.github.com/adampitchie/9a2908efdcd580bc59b2)

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from haversine import *

'''
iterate through shapes and match stops along a shape_pt_sequence within
x amount of distance. for shape_pt_sequence that is closest, replace the stop
lat/lon to the shape_pt_lat/shape_pt_lon, and mark is_stop column with 1.
'''

# readability assignments for shapes.csv
shapes = pd.read_csv('csv/shapes.csv')
shapes_index = list(set(shapes['shape_id']))
shapes_index.sort(key=int)
shapes.set_index(['shape_id', 'shape_pt_sequence'], inplace=True)

# readability assignments for trips.csv
trips = pd.read_csv('csv/trips.csv')
trips_index = list(set(trips['trip_id']))
trips.set_index(['trip_id'], inplace=True)

# readability assignments for stops_times.csv
stop_times = pd.read_csv('csv/stop_times.csv')
stop_times.set_index(['trip_id','stop_sequence'], inplace=True)
print(len(stop_times.loc[1423492]))

# readability assginments for stops.csv
stops = pd.read_csv('csv/stops.csv')
stops.set_index(['stop_id'], inplace=True)

# for each trip_id
for i in trips_index:
    print('******NEW TRIP_ID******')
    print(i)
    i = i.astype(int)

    # for each stop_sequence in stop_times
    for x in range(len(stop_times.loc[i])):
        stop_lat = stop_times.loc[i,['stop_lat','stop_lon']].iloc[x,[0,1]][0]
        stop_lon = stop_times.loc[i,['stop_lat','stop_lon']].iloc[x,[0,1]][1]
        stop_coordinate = (stop_lat, stop_lon)
        print(stop_coordinate)

        # shape_id that matches trip_id
        print('**SHAPE_ID**')
        trips_shape_id = trips.loc[i,['shape_id']].iloc[0]
        trips_shape_id = int(trips_shape_id)
        print(trips_shape_id)

        smallest = 0

        for y in range(len(shapes.loc[trips_shape_id])):
            shape_lat = shapes.loc[trips_shape_id].iloc[y,[0,1]][0]
            shape_lon = shapes.loc[trips_shape_id].iloc[y,[0,1]][1]

            shape_coordinate = (shape_lat, shape_lon)

            haversined = haversine_mi(stop_coordinate, shape_coordinate)

            if smallest == 0 or haversined < smallest:
                smallest = haversined
                smallest_shape_pt_indexer = y
            else:
                pass

            print(haversined)
            print('{0:.20f}'.format(smallest))

        print('{0:.20f}'.format(smallest))
        print(smallest_shape_pt_indexer)

        # mark is_stop as 1
        shapes.iloc[smallest_shape_pt_indexer,[2]] = 1

        # replace coordinate value
        shapes.loc[trips_shape_id].iloc[y,[0,1]][0] = stop_lat
        shapes.loc[trips_shape_id].iloc[y,[0,1]][1] = stop_lon

shapes.to_csv('csv/shapes.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Using `print` takes a long time, have you tried removing them?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do to optmizing this code is use some threads/workers instead those for.

I recommend using the [Pool of Workes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) as its very simple to use.

In:

```
for i in trips_index:
```

You could use something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.apply_async(func, trips_index)
```

And than the method *func* would be like:

```
def func(i):
   #code here
```

And you could simply put the whole *for* loop inside this method.
It would make it work with 4 subprocess in this example, git it a nice improvment.

Comment: I have been trying to implement this, as I would like to try multiprocessing. However, I am having trouble figuring out your suggestion as it is typed. Could you clarify on your answer a little bit?

Comment: i could not test the code as the file "stops.csv" is missing, but i daft something as it shold gets [here](http://pastebin.com/DVDqqxMp). As you're storing the results on shapes to process it to a new csv you would need at last a lock to syncronize the workers as a did on the daft (maybe a datashared would be nice, but Python have some problens in sharing memory of objects).

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is that a collection of trips will often have the same sequence of stops and the same shape data (the only difference between trips is the timing).  So it might make sense to cache the find-closest-point-on-shape operation for (stop_id, shape_id).  I bet that would reduce your runtime by an order-of-magnitude.

Comment: Are you saying that once an entire `shape_id` is computed with stop coordinates and marked as a stop, mark the `shape_id` as computed and skip it next time around?